# Standard for exposing a distributed tracing trace ID in an HTTP response header

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, open-telemetry, distributed-tracing

There is good documentation (OpenTelemetry project, W3C) on generating, passing, and parsing distributed tracing headers (e.g., `traceparent`) on the server side, however I have not found anything authoritative on exposing trace IDs to the client side. E.g., I would like to configure my clients to use the trace ID from an error response to add context to a Sentry log, or allow users to include this information in a support request.

Google Cloud seems to add `X-Cloud-Trace-Context` to responses on at least Cloud Run services... but it's not documented and might not be intentional but present only as a [convenient bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/169349067).

Is there a standard or even a broadly-used convention for this, or is this entirely up to implementations to fashion on their own?

Comment: The W3C Trace Context spec does seem to discourage the use of their reserved headers in responses, at least: "When vendors include traceparent and tracestate headers in responses, these values may inadvertently be passed to cross-origin callers. Vendors should ensure that they include only these response headers when responding to systems that participated in the trace." https://www.w3.org/TR/trace-context/#other-risks

Comment: This comment from one of the spec maintainers seems to indicate the answer is no, but it's a topic of conversation. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59372759/jaeger-traceid-in-response-headers#comment104952575_59372759

Comment: Put your comments in your question. Reserve comments to respond to requests.